# How to implement ARIA tags for Shiny applications to meet WCAG requiremnets?

Tags: html, r, shiny, accessibility, wai-aria

I am writing an application in Shiny that aims to meet WCAG-2.0+ (Web Content Accessibility Guidelines) standards by using ARIA tags (Accessible Rich Internet Applications). Doing so, I tried using html tags embedded within the built in shiny widgets / functions, but with very little success. It seems like Shiny was unable to identify the ARIA tags and there's no way to change it by changing the attributes.

For example, how do I attach an aria tag to the following?

```
a( href = "http://www.thislogo.com")
    img(src = "logo.png",
    title = "The logo",
    height = "60px",
    alt = "This is a picture of the logo, clicking on it links to thislogo.com",
    HTML("aria-label = "logo")
)
```

A second example I tried:

```
a(href = "http://www.thislogo.com",
            img(src = "logo.png",
            title = "The logo",
            height = "60px",
            alt = "This is a picture of the logo, clicking on it links to thislogo.com",
            aria-label = "logo"
        )
    )
```

A third example that didn't work for me:

```
    a(href = "http://www.thislogo.com",
        img(src = "logo.png",
        title = "The logo",
        height = "60px",
        alt = "This is a picture of the logo, clicking on it links to thislogo.com",
        tags$html(aria-label = "logo")
    )
)
```

I was wondering if there's a proper way to implement this and is it even supported for Shiny at the moment? I tried searching everywhere, but this topic seems to be rarely discussed or still in development.

The closest example I found was a discussion on checking for checking accessibility ([link](https://community.rstudio.com/t/making-shiny-apps-accessible-for-all-humans/8458)), or changing the language attribute ([link](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2844)), but not a lot of discussion on actually implementing ARIA tags.

Thanks for your insights.

Comment: All of your examples appear to have mismatched quotes, as in `src = "logo.png'`, is this part of your real code, or just a special typo for this question?

Comment: Thanks for your reply r2evans! It's actually a typo. I'll see if I can correct it by editing. It's just an example for things I tried, I'm more curious whether anyone has sucess using aria tags within the shiny environment. Or the proper way to do it. Cheers!

Comment: It's a fair question, and I'm interested in the topic in general. When questions have typos like that that would likely cause a parsing or completely-unrelated error, it can be frustrating trying to know what you *actually* have. Thanks for making the edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your interest! It is annoying especially when it comes to code, I'll definitely double check next time. Thanks for point it out though, it would've confused others if it wasn't corrected. It's my first time posting on stack overflow, after being a long time lurker, so it's still a learning process. Hope someone will have some insights on the topic :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the attribute you want to add is composed of several words (like "aria" and "label"), you need to wrap it in backticks, like the following:

```r
img(src = "logo.png",
    title = "The logo",
    height = "60px",
    alt = "This is a picture of the logo",
    `aria-label` = "logo")
```

```
<img src="logo.png" title="The logo" height="60px" alt="This is a picture of the logo" aria-label="logo"/>
```